# Android XML Error parsing XML: junk after document element

Tags: android, xml

I am getting this error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
     formed.
    - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element

This is appearing on the second TextView in this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/text1" 
          android:textSize="16sp" 
          android:textStyle="bold" 
          android:textColor="#FFFF00" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    ></TextView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/text3" 
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

Any ideas on the mistake I am making?
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

An XML document can only have 1 root element. You have 3 such elements. You should enclose your TextView elements inside a layout, such as a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- TextView elements here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Remove the xmlns attribute on the first TextView element.

Answer (score 1):

you should encapsule your elements in layouts, such as LinearLayout. You can look at a layout config file in existence.