# What is wrong with my Linear Layout and how I have multiple root tags

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".NotepadV1">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@id/android:list"/>

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@id/android:empty" android:text="@string/no_notes"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried multiple things to fix my problem but can not figure it out. I am using the notepad tutorial from Android studio.

Comment: It would be helpful if you related any errors you've gotten.

Comment: Error:(14) Error parsing XML: junk after document element and it says that I have multiple root tags. Those are the only errors android studio has given me @Politank-Z

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7800744/1055383 and next time search before posting, chances are your question is already been asked and answered.