# Android xml error multiple root

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

So i have this XML and its giving me an error "Multiple root" on the bold. I am copying this example from a book with the purpose to instantiate the MovieLinks fragment ( which will show on a list some movie names) , right after the activity loads the layout. When the user clicks on a item from the list, the application will initiate another activity associated to a second fragment. Can you guys show me what am i doing wrong ? Thanks in advance!!

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <fragment class = "pdm.isel.pt.tmdbapp.MovieLinksFragments"
        android:id="@+id/links" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
**<LinearLayout>**
<fragment class = "pdm.isel.pt.tmdbapp.MovieLinksFragments"
    android:id="@+id/links" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: xml documents can have only ONE root node. you've got two. that's all there is to it. Your `<LinearLayout>` is **OUTSIDE** of the `<framelayout>` tag, therefore it's a second root node.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800682/android-xml-error-parsing-xml-junk-after-document-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275533/multiple-root-tags-in-android-studio?rq=1) SO links talk about this issue.

If you move the `LinearLayout` tag inside `FrameLayout` that will get rid of your issue at hand. I changed the xml you posted to make it compile, but you need to revisit your book to copy the correct xml. This does not seem alright to me.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <fragment class = "pdm.isel.pt.tmdbapp.MovieLinksFragments"
        android:id="@+id/links" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <fragment class = "pdm.isel.pt.tmdbapp.MovieLinksFragments"
            android:id="@+id/links1" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```