# I don't know what is happening

Tags: android

I am trying to add a action bar to my layout but it is giving me a multiple root tag error.

Here is my code.

please help me

EDIT:

Here is the full xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/c1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/c1"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple root tags in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275533/multiple-root-tags-in-android-studio)

Comment: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  remove this from Toolbar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800682/android-xml-error-parsing-xml-junk-after-document-element

Comment: is this the full XML?

Comment: no ill add the full one

Comment: okay it is added to the original question

Comment: Can you see it?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your xml file. 
1. ScrollView can have only one child. If you want more than one wrap them in a layout. 2. Learn about xml schemas and then start adding it to your xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this layout structure:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/c1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
                android:text="asdf"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. ScrollView can have only one child. If you want more than one, wrap them in a layout.
> 2. There must be only one root layout in any xml file. Learn about root tag and xml namespaces

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/c1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
        android:background="#00FF00"/>

    </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```